# How to have a div show in two different jquery tabs but not the third?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've got a page with three tabs on it, each with different content.  I also have a div with a select and a button.  I would like this div to display on the first two tabs but not the third.  I know one option would be to just duplicate the content on both tabs, but then I would have to keep their data in sync with javascript and I feel like there has to be a better solution than that.

So I tried putting the div between where the tabs are defined and where the tab content starts, which works fine, but it makes it show in all three tabs.  In the javascript, I tried binding click events to the tab buttons

```
$("#pushingInfoTabButton").click(function () {
        $("#addInspection").show();
});
$("#pushingInspTabButton").click(function () {
        $("#addInspection").show();
});
$("#pushingGridTabButton").click(function () {
        $("#addInspection").hide();
});
```

and showing the div in two tabs and hiding with the third, but after putting `debugger` inside of the click events, they never fire.  Is there an easier way to do this that I'm just unaware of?

Here's the corresponding HTML.  Sorry for not having it at first.

```
        <div data-role="tabs" class="ui-content insetContent infoContent" >
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="pushingInfoTabButton" href="#pushingInfoTab" data-theme="a">Info</a></li>
                    <li><a id="pushingInspTabButton" href="#pushingInspTab" data-theme="a">Insp</a></li>
                    <li><a id="pushingGridTabButton" href="#pushingGridTab" data-theme="a">Grid</a></li>
                </ul>                
            </div>
            <div id="addInspection">
                <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:30%;margin-right:0px;">
                    <a data-role="button" data-inline="false" data-theme="b"  style="padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px;" id="A1">Add</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b" text-align:right" style="width:70%; margin-left:0px;">
                    <select data-inline="true"  data-native-menu="true">
                        <option value=""  id="Option1">Select</option>
                    </select>
                    <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="g"  style="margin-left:-7px;" id="A2">Clr</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="pushingInfoTab" class="ui-content insetContent infoContent">

            </div>
            <div id="pushingInspTab" class="ui-content insetContent infoContent">

            </div>
            <div id="pushingGridTab" class="ui-content insetContent infoContent">

            </div>
```

Notice:  Didn't put any of the content that's actually in the tabs, because it's hundreds of lines of unnecessary markup, and I don't think it's the issue.

Comment: We'd need to see the corresponding HTML code.

Comment: @JeremyThille added.  Sorry, figured it was a simple enough question the HTML wouldn't be necessary

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes, how would I use that in this situation?  I've used it before for select boxes, but I don't know how it would be relevant here.

Comment: Indeed, this code should work, I think. You say the click events never fire, maybe that's the problem. What if you do `$("#pushingInfoTabButton").click(function () {
        alert();
});` ?

Comment: I do not see any issue in firing of event. Is that your real question? Or are you looking for some optimized method to achieve same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo error here:

```
text-align:right" style="wi
```

Then, put the JS at the bottom of the body, or at jQuery Document Ready.

Here is the [working demo](http://jsbin.com/zeyafanude/1/edit?html,console,output).

Comment: Yes. Agree. Always make a demo. :)